# Format not working in emacs + slime + sbcl

Tags: format, sbcl, slime

I'm running emacs + slime + sbcl on an iMac High Sierra version 10.13.6.  When I evaluate (format t "This is a test ~%) in the *slime-repl sbcl*, sbcl simply returns nil without printing the output.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Removed tag `emacs`, though you are using Emacs, because the `format` you're asking about is (presumably) Common Lisp `format` and not Elisp `format`. (The latter does not have a destination first arg.)

Comment: did you check the "inferior-lisp" buffer (there are additional asterisks around the name but I can't write them in this comment box); or maybe if you started lisp in a terminal and connected to it, if that's printed in that terminal ?